# There exists a real number y so that for all real numbers x, x + y is rational true or false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I think it is false . 
the negetion would be

For all real numbers y , there exits a real number x for which x+y is irrational . I have no idea how to prove the negation is true here.

Comment: Given $y$, can you solve $x+y=\sqrt2$ for $x$?

Comment: Thanks ! got it i choose x = root 2 - y and that works for all values of y i guess

Comment: As stated, $y$ is fixed and works for every real number. Thus $y$ must itself be rational, but then $y+\sqrt{2}$ cannot be, thus violating your condition.

Answer (score 3):

$(z-y) + y$ is irrational whenever $z$ is irrational.

Comment: @Arthur You’re right. I’ve started out with two special cases, but midway I decided to do the general case because it seemed more illustrative.